# Связь один ко многим, не создает таблицу в Postgrsql

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Подскажите в чем ошибка.
Class UsersEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userEntity", schema = "public")
public class UsersEntity implements java.io.Serializable{
    private Integer userId;
    private String name;
    private Integer date;
    private String username;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private Set<Stock> stock = new HashSet<Stock>(
            0);

    public UsersEntity() {
    }

    public UsersEntity(Integer userId, String name, Integer date, String username,
                       String phone, String email, String password, String country,
                       Set<Stock> stock) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "user_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public Integer getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Integer date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userEntity")
    public Set<Stock> getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Set<Stock> stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
```

Class Stock :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", schema = "public")
public class Stock {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private UsersEntity usersEntity;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    public UsersEntity getUser() {
        return this.usersEntity;
    }

    public void setUser(UsersEntity usersEntity) {
        this.usersEntity = usersEntity;
    }
```

hibernate.xml :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/personal2</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

        <mapping class="Entity.UsersEntity"/>
        <mapping class="Entity.Stock"/>
```

Exception :

```
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Entity.Stock.userEntity in Entity.UsersEntity.stock
```

Comment: mappedBy = "userEntity", где у вас userEntity в Stock?

Comment: В Stock нету, в Stock  другая таблица. name = "stock"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", schema = "public")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 207833019233866146L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_entity_id", nullable = false)
    private UsersEntity usersEntity;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(Long id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public UsersEntity getUsersEntity() {
        return usersEntity;
    }

    public void setUsersEntity(UsersEntity usersEntity) {
        this.usersEntity = usersEntity;
    }

}


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users_entity", schema = "public")
public class UsersEntity implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2972756330752762332L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "user_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private Integer date;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usersEntity")
    private Set<Stock> stock;

    public UsersEntity() {
    }

    public UsersEntity(Long id, String name, Integer date, String username,
                       String phone, String email, String password, String country,
                       Set<Stock> stock) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Integer date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Set<Stock> getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Set<Stock> stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void addStock(Stock stock) {
        if (this.stock==null) this.stock = new HashSet<>();
        this.stock.add(stock);
    }

}
```

Comment: Тогда переписывайте классы так и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: Не за что. Обратите внимание на то, на правила именование полей, таблиц в бд. Дело в том, что бд нерегистрозависимая, поэтому писать класс UserEntity будет представлен таблицей user_entity, причем даже без аннотации Table. Т.е. вместо верблюжей нотации ставится _. Кроме того, именовать класс Entity как-то некрасиво, лучше поместите их в один пакет. И еще, все аннотации пишите на полях , а не на геттерах сеттерах. Причин несколько. Основная в том, что геттеры и сеттеры генерируются любой средой разработки автоматически. И зачастую их просто нужно удалить и сгенерить заново. А еще есть Lombok))

Comment: Большое спасибо, за информаию

Answer (score 0):

В классе UsersEntity исправьте строчку со связью, чтобы она имела такой вид @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usersEntity"). Вы имеете дело с объектной моделью, когда вы пишите mappedBy = "userEntity", то хибернейт пытается найти поле userEntity в классе сток, а там у вас такого поля нет, там usersEntity. Отсюда ошибка

Comment: Сделал, ничего не поменяялось